# Alternative Wubi for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wubi

I search alternative Wu bi ... I would Install Ubuntu in Disk C:\  with Files Windows.. in Wubi it's very awkward (Wubi is discontinued so..) 
Someone have any  form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a replacement for WUBI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751182/is-there-a-replacement-for-wubi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wubi: Cannot download metalink and therefore the ISO (Change?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661729/wubi-cannot-download-metalink-and-therefore-the-iso-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a proper dual boot or use a virtual machine if your hardware is powerful enough.

Comment: Why anyone would choose wine over vbox or vmware is beyond me :P

Comment: Thanks,  but i Look for alternative for wubi ( other programs work as Wubi)

Comment: There are no other software but using a virtual machine should give pretty much The same performance.