# Installation of Ubuntu dually with Windows 7 using wubi

Tags: xubuntu

i am Jay.. i've been trying to install ubuntu dually with windows 7 using wubi.

this error message pops " could not retrieve the required disk image files "

here's the log file> c:\users\jay-o\appdta\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev266.log

i took the following steps in attempting the installation:

1. downloaded the wubi.exe file from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. converted the .exe file to .iso since the error message above popped
3. moved both of the to an empty file
4. ran the installation as administrator
5. tried getting help from you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Also 12.04 expires in April, so best to install 16.04 or 14.04. Also most Windows 7 installs used all 4 primary BIOS/MBR partitions, if so: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Where did you find a link at https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop  for a wubi.exe ? Currently, there are linked downloads for 16.04.1 LTS and 16.10 which don't contain a wubi.exe. Possible duplicate of [is there a replacement for Wubi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751182/is-there-a-replacement-for-wubi)

Answer (score 2):

Wubi installs are no longer supported.

Use the standard Ubuntu installer to install Ubuntu either by itself, or in a dual-boot configuration. You could also install Virtualbox into Windows, and Ubuntu into Virtualbox.

Comment: See this link and links from it for more details, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766